# Inserting a text file into a Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>>

Tags: java, object, arraylist, hashmap

This is my first question here so please bear with me. I have a text file that looks like something like this;

userId,itemId,rating
1,101,2.5
4,103,3.0
1,103,3.0
6,104,3.5
2,101,3.0
4,106,4.5
2,103,1.5
5,102,4.0
2,105,3.5
7,106,3.0
3,101,2.5
3,102,3.0

What I'am trying to accomplish is to read the file line per line and seperated each value. After that is done place all unique userIds in the key section of this map; `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>>`. And place the itemIds with the rating in the second map corresponding to the key of the first map. Can you still follow me?? Here is the code I produced so far with not the outcome I want.

This is my User class:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class User {
    private int mUserId;
    private Map<Integer, Double> mRatedItems;

    public User(int userId) {
        mUserId = userId;
        mRatedItems = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return mUserId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        mUserId = userId;
    }

    public Map<Integer, Double> getRatedItems() {
        return mRatedItems;
    }

    public void addRatedItems(int itemId, double rating) {
        mRatedItems.put(itemId, rating);
    }
}
```

This is the file I need to modify:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

public class TextFile {
    List<User> mUserIdList;
    private User mUser;

    public Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>> readFile(String fileName) {
        mUserIdList = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>> userItemData = new HashMap<>();

        try (
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis))
        ) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] args = line.split(",");

                int userId = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                int itemId = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                double rating = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);

                if (!mUserIdList.contains(userId)) {
                    mUser = new User(userId);
                    mUserIdList.add(mUser);
                }

                if (!mUserIdList.isEmpty()) {
                    addItemRatings(userId, itemId, rating);
                }

                if (!checkDuplicates()) {
                    userItemData.put(mUser.getUserId(), mUser.getRatedItems());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.printf("Problem loading: %s %n", fileName);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return userItemData;
    }  

    private boolean checkDuplicates() {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (User user : mUserIdList) {
            if (!set.add(user.getUserId())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void addItemRatings(int userId, int itemId, double rating) {
        for (User user : mUserIdList) {
            if (user.getUserId() == userId) {
                user.addRatedItems(itemId, rating);
            }
        }
    }

    public int showTextLines(String fileName) {
        int textLines = 0;
        try (
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis))
        ) {
            while (reader.readLine() != null) {
                textLines++;
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.printf("Problem showing total lines from: %s %n", fileName);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return textLines;
    }
}
```

This is my main class:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TextFile textFile = new TextFile();
        String location = "D:\\IdeaProjects\\KMeans\\src\\com\\quincy\\userItem1.data";
        Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>> readFile = textFile.readFile(location);
        int textLines = textFile.showTextLines(location);
        System.out.printf("File: %s %n", readFile);
        System.out.printf("Number of lines in file: %s %n", textLines);
    }
}
```

And my output is:

```
File: {1={101=2.5, 103=3.0}, 4={103=3.0, 106=4.5}} 
Number of lines in file: 12
```

My code is only adding the first two userIds with their corresponding itemIds and rating. Can somebody please explain to me what I' am doing wrong?? And maybe show how I can improve this code to work properly??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the app yourself? Are you using eclipse? http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: Yes I have tried debugging the code. I'm using intellij idea to write my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `checkDuplicates()` method. I don't know what exactly you're trying to achieve on that function but if you want to check for duplications. then, I suggest you just use the function `containsKey()` like this.

```
if (!userItemData.containsKey(mUser.getUserId())) {
     userItemData.put(mUser.getUserId(), mUser.getRatedItems());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kucing_terbang I was looking for the solution for hours. This solutions works for me!!